# duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_SOSPicker._quality Compile error... Cordova camera

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3

I am working with an ionic camera demo. I am getting this error.

duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_SOSPicker._quality

duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_SOSPicker.callbackId in:
    /Users/philipwilson/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/IonicImageHandlingTutorial-adzezmwycmxskoaspvkefuaqlbxl/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/IonicImageHandlingTutorial/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/IonicImageHandlingTutorial.build/Debug-iphoneos/IonicImageHandlingTutorial.build/Objects-normal/armv7/SOSPicker-2EB1A7C0CEDC4077.o

these are the versions install on my mac.

~/workspace/ionic_images/test1/ionic3-image-handling$ ionic -v 3.20.0
~/workspace/ionic_images/test1/ionic3-image-handling$ cordova -v 8.0.0
~/workspace/ionic_images/test1/ionic3-image-handling$ node -v v10.4.0
~/workspace/ionic_images/test1/ionic3-image-handling$ npm -v 6.1.0

https://github.com/ionicthemes/ionic3-image-handling

https://ionicthemes.com/tutorials/about/ionic-2-image-handling#comment-3934178891

Anyone know what this error is from on compile?
Thanks
Phil

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok..I got is working.. I went into xcode and removed the SOSPicker.. Strange. stuf..

that something got duplicated on your iOS app. I see 2 choices here, open xcode and delete the duplicated symbol SOSPicker or delete platforms and plugins folders from your ionic project and generate them again.